# Showing $|x|^\alpha$ is an $A_p$ weight for $-d<\alpha<d(p-1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-analysis

We say $w:\mathbb{R}^d \to [0,\infty)$ is an $A_p$ weight if
$$\frac{1}{|B|}\int_B w \left(\frac{1}{|B|}\int_Bw^{1-p'}\right)^{p-1} \le C(p)$$ for all balls $B$, and where $p'$ is the holder conjugate of $p>1$. We want to show $|x|^\alpha$ is an $A_p$ weight if and only if $d<\alpha<d(p-1)$. Here is my progress:

First take balls centered at the origin. We have
$$\frac{1}{|B(0,r)|}\int_{B(0,r)}w(x) \ dx =\frac{1}{c(d)r^d} \int_0^r \int_{\partial B(x,s)} |x|^\alpha \ dS(x) \ ds =\frac{1}{c(d)r^d} \int_0^r dc(d) s^{\alpha + d-1} \ ds$$
converges if and only if $\alpha >-d$ (i.e., $r^c$ is integrable at $0$ if and only if $c>-1$), and in this case is equal to 
$$= \frac{d}{\alpha + d}r^{\alpha} <\infty$$
And then
$$\left(\frac{1}{|B(0,r)|}\int_{B(0,r)} w^{1-p'} \right)^{p-1} = \left(\frac{1}{c(d)r^d} \int_0^r \int_{\partial B(0,s)} s^{\alpha - \alpha p'} \ dS(x) \ ds\right)^{p-1}$$
$$= \left(\frac{1}{c(d)r^d} \int_0^r dc(d) s^{\alpha - \alpha p' + d-1} \ ds\right)^{p-1}$$

$$ =\left(\frac{d}{\alpha - \alpha p ' + d}\right)^{p-1} r^{\alpha (1-p')(p-1)}$$
$$=\left(\frac{d}{\alpha - \alpha p ' + d}\right)^{p-1} r^{-\alpha}$$
where the last integral converges if and only if $\alpha(1-p') + d = \alpha \cdot \displaystyle \frac{-1}{p-1} +d >0$, or, if $\alpha <d(p-1)$. Then we see multiplying the two expressions we get a constant.

So, we definitely have necessity of our range. Sufficiency is a bit harder, because we have to show it for any balls.

For balls $B(y,r)$ with $|y|\le r$ we can simply extend the domain of integration to get
$$\frac{1}{c(d)r^d}\int_{B(y,r)}\left(\frac{1}{c(d)r^d}\int_{B(0,r)}|x|^{\alpha(1-p')}\right)^{p-1}$$
$$\le \frac{C}{r^{dp}} \int_{B(0,|y|+r)}|x|^\alpha \left(\int_{B(0,|y|+r)}|x|^{\alpha(1-p')}\right)^{p-1}$$
$$\le C\frac{(|y|+r)^{dp}}{r^{dp}} \le C$$
since we use $|y| \le r$.

But I don't know how to extend to balls with $|y|>r$. Any tips? In general I just don't know how to deal with these integrals over balls not centered at origin.

Comment: Wait, my.uchicago says Schlag's class is cancelled?

Comment: He's intense $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have taken care of the most "troublesome" balls already!

Fist observe that your argument for balls $|y|\le r$ works also if $|y|\le Cr$ for some constant $C>1$ (imagine $C=10^{10}$).

That means we may assume $|y|>Cr$. That is, the radius of the ball is small (imagine tiny) compared to its distance from the origin.

As a consequence, we expect the average $\frac1{|B|}\int_B |x|^\beta$ to be roughly $|y|^\beta$ for all real $\beta$.

Making this precise, I'm claiming that we have $\frac1{|B|}\int_B |x|^\beta\lesssim |y|^\beta$ (try to prove this).

(Here, $\lesssim$ denotes $\le$ up to a multiplicative constant.)

This implies
$$\left(\frac1{|B|}\int_B w\right)\left(\frac{1}{|B|}\int_B w^{1-p'}\right)^{p-1} \lesssim |y|^\alpha |y|^{\alpha (1-p')(p-1)} = 1.$$

We didn't even need to make use of the constraint on $\alpha$ in this case.

Comment: Ah yes, my professor showed me exactly this. Very nice, and hopefully an idea I won’t forget. Thank you!